# MSSQL: Remove Duplicate Words in Each Row of Table

Tags: python, sql, string, duplicates

I have a column called "Text" that is a bunch of strings.  I want to remove duplicate words in each row even if the words are non-consecutive.

Below is a sample table. The "Desired_Column" shows the end result I want.

```
   ID     Text                Desired_Column    
    1     Ant Apple Ant Dog   Ant Apple Dog 
    2     A B C C             A B C
    3     You Me He           You Me He
```

I have been able to successfully write the code to do this task in python but can't figure out how to do it in SQL.

Below is my python code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df_EVENT5_13['ADDED_REQS_3'] = df_EVENT5_13['ADDED_REQS_2'].str.split().apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()).str.join(' ')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't think there are any built in functions to do this in Oracle or MySql. You can write a user defined function to do it though. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes ... I can do user defined functions in Python but have no clue how to do it in SQL